# Only show data that is in database more than 5 times

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a report that works fine apart from my final hurdle.

Table Example, Row A:

```
John
John
Mike
John
Steve
Steve
```

I only want my report to show name that are in my table 5 times or more. I'm struggling to work out what criteria I need to set

Any advice?

---

from comment:

```
SELECT tblSourceData.Athlete, Max(tblSourceData.Swim) AS MaxOfSwim, 
    Max(tblSourceData.Bike) AS MaxOfBike, Max(tblSourceData.Run) AS MaxOfRun 
FROM tblSourceData 
GROUP BY tblSourceData.Athlete, tblSourceData.Gender 
HAVING (((tblSourceData.Athlete)>="5") AND ((tblSourceData.Gender)="f"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [`HAVING` clause](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HAVING-Clause-64c52dba-5cda-45c5-98b5-bd155a89f02f).

```
SELECT aName, Count(aName) AS NumName
FROM myTable
GROUP BY aName
HAVING Count(aName)>=5
```

**Edit**

you probably want

```
SELECT tblSourceData.Athlete, Max(tblSourceData.Swim) AS MaxOfSwim, 
    Max(tblSourceData.Bike) AS MaxOfBike, Max(tblSourceData.Run) AS MaxOfRun 
FROM tblSourceData 
WHERE tblSourceData.Gender="f"
GROUP BY tblSourceData.Athlete 
HAVING Count(tblSourceData.Athlete)>=5
```

Criteria that don't use aggregated columns go into the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I am using the following but not woring: SELECT tblSourceData.Athlete, Max(tblSourceData.Swim) AS MaxOfSwim, Max(tblSourceData.Bike) AS MaxOfBike, Max(tblSourceData.Run) AS MaxOfRun
FROM tblSourceData
GROUP BY tblSourceData.Athlete, tblSourceData.Gender
HAVING (((tblSourceData.Athlete)>="5") AND ((tblSourceData.Gender)="f"));

Comment: @david: **Please** don't post code in comments. Edit your question and post it there.

Comment: No problem - I can see you have already added it. I know for future where to put in. Thanks

Comment: This worked - Would you mind explaining why my SQL didnt work? from the design view both mine and yours appear the same so cant work out what I was doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Mainly you were missing the `Count` function for the Athlete column. So you were comparing the original string to 5, and Access changed that to `"5"`. For Gender, change "Group by" to "Condition", this removes it from GROUP BY and HAVING and puts the condition into WHERE.

Comment: ahhh I see - Makes perfect sense now, doh! Thank you for the help